# Client side validation by using "RequiredFieldValidator" is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, telerik, client-side-validation

I am trying to implement `RequiredFieldValidator` into my ASP.NET page. It's working well when I click "Submit" button. However, client side validation doesn't work. How to show the warning when user clears this area go to the next control?

```
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" Runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Width="320px" RenderMode="Lightweight">
                            </telerik:RadTextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TextBoxRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                            ControlToValidate="RadTextBox1" ErrorMessage="The textbox cannot be empty" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this entry into web.config solved the issue.

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```